# WebAPI HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies NULL despite checks

Tags: vb.net, cookies, asp.net-apicontroller

For the past year, I have been working on an application that calls an API with no problem.

Since deployment every so often the error logging I have throws up the most peculiar error, the oh so helpful Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Time: 08:22

Type: System.NullReferenceException

Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Method: PostClocking

File: SS_PostClocking

Stack: SS_PostClocking.vb:line 71
at SS_PostClocking.vb:line 17
```

Check the lines the only code on this line is `Dim c = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies`

I downloaded the production database and was entirely unable to replicate the issue, as has no one else using any browser in my team.

As a result over the past few days, I have added the following directly above in an attempt to see what exactly is going on.

```
Try
    If HttpContext.Current Is Nothing Then
        ErrorLogging.WriteLog("[Self service post clocking] HttpContext.Current is nothing")
        Throw New ManagedException("This action failed, please refresh and try again.")
    End If
        
    If HttpContext.Current.Request Is Nothing Then
        ErrorLogging.WriteLog("[Self service post clocking] HttpContext.Current.Request is nothing")
        Throw New ManagedException("This action failed, please refresh and try again.")
    End If

    If HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies Is Nothing Then
        ErrorLogging.WriteLog("[Self service post clocking] HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies is nothing")
        Throw New ManagedException("This action failed, please refresh and try again.")
    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    ErrorLogging.WriteLog(ex)
    If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then ErrorLogging.WriteLog(ex.InnerException)
    Throw New ManagedException("This action failed, please refresh and try again.")
End Try

Dim c = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies
```

Unbelievably I now get errors on the exact same line, `Dim c = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies` despite the checks previous.

The most frustrating thing is the API is called in excess of 5000x throughout the day successfully by multiple clients, and yet one for some unknown reason fails.

I have denied cookies when doing some tests but cannot even log into the system under these circumstances, so it can't be that.

Totally confused, any ideas or suggestions would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

**cause 1**

Cookies only work on a postback. it does not work when there is no request done.

if no user has requested the action trough an url, cookies is null.

Try call your code from page and control events. such as page.load / page.init

**Cause 2**

one of your users might have disabled browser cookies.